# How to combine multiple try-except blocks?

Tags: python, loops, exception, try-except

I have a bunch of statements I want to use try, except on. Yes bad practise.

There must be a more pythonic way to write the following?

```
try:
    E1=clean_html.find("span",{"class":"range-a"}).text
except AttributeError:
    E1=None

try:
    E2=clean_html.find("span",{"class":"range-b"}).text 
except AttributeError:
    E2=None

try:
    E3=clean_html.find("span",{"class":"range-c"}).text 
except AttributeError:
    E3=None

try:
    E4=clean_html.find("div",{"class":"Description"}).get_text(separator=" ").strip()
except AttributeError:
    E4=None
```

Because this code works fine for me, but it looks unefficient.

Comment: You can create a function which does this, or a context manager, but whatever you do, you should not have a bare `except:`! See what the actual exception is and catch that, e.g. `except IndexError:`.

Comment: Adjusted it accordingly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function that handles the try and except. You can pass the post_processing as a lambda if you want the function to handle the problem of None throwing errors when calling methods on it

```py
def get_clean_text(tag, class_name, post_processor):
    try:
        return post_processor(clean_html.find(tag,{"class": class_name}))
    except AttributeError:
        return None

E1 = get_clean_text("span", "range-a", lambda o: o.text)
E4 = get_clean_text("div", "Description", lambda o: o.get_text(separator=" ").strip())
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer worked, and prettified my code a lot ! :) If the attribute would change from class to something different, the function would have to be altered right?

Comment: Yes, then you probably need to pass the full second argument of `clean_html.find()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a default to the variables and then do the work. Since you want the default to be the immutable `None`, you can

```
E1 = E2 = E3 = E4 = None

try:
    E1=clean_html.find("span",{"class":"range-a"}).text
    E2=clean_html.find("span",{"class":"range-b"}).text 
    E3=clean_html.find("span",{"class":"range-c"}).text 
    E4=clean_html.find("div",{"class":"Description"}).get_text(separator=" ").strip()
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

The best way to handle exceptions depends on more context than we have here, but generally you want to write larger blocks that stay in a sane state on any "exceptional" operation.

Since exceptions take some processing power to setup and may be visually untidy, testing (especially when wrapped in its own function) can be a better way to go.

```
def get_elem_text(elem, default=None):
    if elem:
        return elem.text
    else:
        return default

E1=get_elem_text(clean_html.find("span",{"class":"range-a"}))
E2=get_elem_text(clean_html.find("span",{"class":"range-b"})) 
E3=get_elem_text(clean_html.find("span",{"class":"range-c"})) 
# I don't know what "get_text" is so can't abstract it
#E4=get_elem_text(clean_html.find("div",{"class":"Description"}), default="")).strip()
```

Comment: Dear tdelaney, thank you for your answer. I have indeed considered this, but than, if E1 errors out, it would go to except, and not perform E2, E3 and E4. I would like to execute all of them

Comment: @Rivered - Added another often used method.

Comment: For the example I wrote another function to encompass E4. But actually when I want to do some splits processing of the elements found by get_elem_text, such as .split("/")[-1] it will run into a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable, as makes sense since this element will be None if its not there.. I still have a feeling there must be a more logical way with try except

Comment: You could make an empty string the default instead of `None` to make split work. You could rewrite `get_elem_text` to use exceptions instead of the test, but in this case the test will be a bit faster and you'd have the same problem of splitting `None`. The fix may best be handled in your processing code. `if E4: do the split and processing`.